# load second content onclick in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a page with some fact boxes, so I have made these divs with classes on with two

tag text blocks, the second block have 'display none' on it and should first be shown when you click on the div.

And that's my problem I would like to make a Jquery function that loads the second paragraph in when I click on the div i just don't know how to tell the site that its specifically that' paragraph without using any id or classes that would trigger all the other divs.

**here is my code:**

```
 <div id="content">
       <div class="teaser-box">
             <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p><!-- paragraph 1 (shown) -->
             <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p><!-- paragraph 2 (not shown) -->
       </div>

       <div class="teaser-box">
             <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p><!-- paragraph 1 (shown) -->
             <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p><!-- paragraph 2 (not shown) -->
       </div>

       <div class="teaser-box">
             <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p><!-- paragraph 1 (shown) -->
             <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p><!-- paragraph 2 (not shown) -->
       </div>

       <div id="load-teas"><h4>Load more</h4></div>


  </div><!-- content END -->
```

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever a div is clicked, you get reference to the div in `this`

now you just need to find the `last child` of this div and `show` it

something like:

```
 $('.teaser-box').click(function() { 

$(this).children(':last').show();
        return false; 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use another [Jquery Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) like [:nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), in your function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.teaser-box').click(function () {
      $('p:nth-child(2)',this).show();
   })
})
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/KC63V/4/**

Answer (score 0):

Bind click on each boxes and show the second `p` child of the box (`eq(1)`)

```
$(".teaser-box").click(function(){
   $(this).find("p").eq(1).show();
}
```

Comment: But its not really what im looking for i think i asked the  question a bit wrong but i need to click on the individual divs the boxes contains one block of text which is shown when you load the page and then you click on the div box and the other (number two) text block is being shown if you know what i mean.

Comment: Sorry got to click send a bit to fast :)